# How do you change the acceleration of a tennis ball, connected to a string in circular motion?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, acceleration, string

I'm a freshman in high school. In Physics we have a question in our lab that I would like to have help on. In the lab, we have a flying pig (or tennis ball) tied up to a string that's connected to the ceiling, and one of the questions in the lab asks us to find two ways to decrease the acceleration. I think one way might be increasing the length of the string, but I really don't have a clue on the second way.

Comment: how many equations for circular motion do you know / have been given?

Comment: Is increasing the radius, or decreasing the speed of revolution allowed?

Comment: Rotating at slower $ \omega$